# Criar e preencher elementos com retorno do json em jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Boa noite, pessoal.

Preciso pegar um retorno json e montar um html com os dados dinamicamente. Cheguei até a parte de conseguir pegar o json e nada mais, estou travado.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "products.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $(data.cart.item).each(function (index, product) {
            
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="hide-scroller">
                <div class="hide-product">
                    <img class="hide-img" src="img/note-gamer-acer-160-160.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="colum-product">
                        <p id="name">Notebook Gamer Acer</p>
                        <p id="quant">Qtd.: 1 <span id="total">R$ 7.158,21</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem várias formas de se fazer isso. Usando a [API repositórios do GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/), podemos fazer um exemplo:

```js
const API_URL = 'https://api.github.com/users/lffg/repos?sort=updated';

function generateHTML(data) {
  const repositories = data;
  const $list = $('.list');

  for (const repository of repositories) {
    // Criamos um elemento `<a>`, adicionamos o texto e alguns atributos:
    const $item = $('<a>');
    $item.css('display', 'block');
    $item.text(repository.name);
    $item.attr('href', `https://github.com/${repository.full_name}`);

    // Inserimos o elemento que criamos acima (o `<a>`) na lista.
    $list.append($item);
  }
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: API_URL,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: generateHTML
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <!-- Os itens serão adicionados aqui dinâmicamente. -->
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, como a API do GitHub retorna uma estrutura em JSON da seguinte maneira:

```
[
  { /* Objeto de um repositório. */ },
  { /* Objeto de outro repositório. */ },
  // ...
]
```

Devemos iterar sobre cada elemento do array. É por isso que temos a seguinte declaração:

> ```
> const repositories = data;
> ```

Se você tiver um JSON mais ou menos assim:

```
{
  "items": [
    { /* Objeto de um repositório. */ },
    { /* Objeto de outro repositório. */ },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Deverá o trecho destacado acima para:

```js
const repositories = data.items;
```

Para saber mais sobre essa notação, leia [assessores de propriedade](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) na MDN.

---

Se você quiser elaborar um template um pouco mais avançado, pode usar as [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). Deixo também um exemplo com um HTML um pouco mais complexo:

```js
const API_URL = 'https://api.github.com/users/lffg/repos?sort=updated';

function generateHTML(data) {
  const repositories = data;
  const $list = $('.list');

  for (const repository of repositories) {
    const $item = $(`
      <div class="item">
        <strong>${repository.name}</strong>
        <em>Linguagem: ${repository.language}</em>
        <a href="https://github.com/${repository.full_name}" target="_blank">
          Link ->
        </a>
      </div>
    `);

    // Inserimos o elemento que criamos acima na lista:
    $list.append($item);
  }
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: API_URL,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: generateHTML
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: solid 1px #555;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item > * {
  display: block;
}

.item > strong {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list"></div>
```